# Does the HttpClientCertificate return any "signed" data?

Tags: c#, https, certificate, smartcard, client-certificates

I'm working on a research story involving web-based Smart Card authentication. We've managed to set up an environment that requires Smart Card PIN entry during the authentication process, but there's some disagreement about whether the resulting `HttpClientCertificate` includes any information representing a signature (i.e., some arbitrary data encrypted with the PIN/private key on the Smart Card).

Does anyone have experience dealing with signatures like this? I'm having real trouble finding examples describing any kind of web-based Smart Card/PIN authentication and then recording data from the `HttpClientCertificate` that would verify the signature.

Comment: No special experience with http certificates, but any certificate has a signature covering the [hash of the] public key (here: of the card), and signed either with the corresponding private key (self-signed cert.) or more likely with the private key from the CA, which verified the identity of the card holder.

Comment: Thanks - I think your comment answers my question - I was under the impression that the Certificate property on this class represented what you described. We're still waiting for a our server admin to set up a test environment to confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpClientCertificate`, as the name suggests, contains the *certificate* (typically following X.509). So it does not contain "arbitrary" data encrypted with the PIN/private key on the smartcard (I assume you are actually trying to refer to session authentication data).

The certificate consists of only static data, which is

- the public key that the certificate was issued for,
- some metadata (such as identifying information for the key pair, parameters of the public-key cryptosystem, validity periods, usage constraints, etc.), and
- a signature over that static data, which is either issued by a cerificate authority (in case a certificate authority issued the certificate) or created with the private key that corresponds to the public key in the certificate (in case of a self-signed certificate / CA root certificate, though this should not be the case for TLS client certificates).

So `HttpClientCertificate` neither contains the private key associated with the certificate nor any dynamic data signed by the private key in order to authenticate the TLS session.

Comment: Thanks for the information - we'd been given some pretty vague requirements for certificate-based authentication, so the wording in my question was based around the requirements we'd been given at the time. We're using Smart Cards that have both PIN-based certificates and a digital signature certificate. From your perspective, is there any meaningful distinction between those two? We've only been able to get the PIN-based authentication to work, and the client's telling us that the digital signature is preferable for reasons that they can't actually define.